# Google Drive API inserting file into Team Drive Folder and My Drive

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

I am trying to upload files to particular location on google drive but i can't upload it to specific drive. I have correct authorization for API. But i don't correct path to upload those files. Please any suggestion would be great.

Comment: too broad. can you specify which platform you're doing this in - Android, Web, etc?

Comment: It would be web